# TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function

Tags: reactjs

I have a data.js file where I have this:

```
export default [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Black shirt Friday outfit",
    price: 30.99,
    image:URL("../images/black-shirt.jpg")
},
{
    id:2,
    title:"Look at me in brown boots",
    price:25.30,
    // image: (url("../images/brown-outfit.jpg"))
},
{
    id:3,
    title:"Cute winter",
    price: 21.90,
    // image: url("../images/cozy-outfit.jpg"),
},
```

My question is: What syntax can I use to render those images in my react-app?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone desperately searching for the answer its in error message

you need to type "new" in front of URL so new URL

example below

```
export default [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Black shirt Friday outfit",
    price: 30.99,
    image: new URL("../images/black-shirt.jpg")
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import them and then reference them:

```js
import Image1 from "../images/black-shirt.jpg"
import Image2 from "../images/brown-outfit.jpg"
import Image3 from "../images/cozy-outfit.jpg"

**export default [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Black shirt Friday outfit",
    price: 30.99,
    image: Image1
},
{
    id:2,
    title:"Look at me in brown boots",
    price:25.30,
    image: Image2
},
{
    id:3,
    title:"Cute winter",
    price: 21.90,
    image: Image3
},**
```

Then when you want to use them in a component, you'd refer directly to that imported object as the source:

```js
data.map( item => 
   <img src={item.image} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Black shirt Friday outfit",
        price: 30.99,
        image:"../images/black-shirt.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        title:"Look at me in brown boots",
        price:25.30,
        image: "../images/black-shirt.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        title:"Cute winter",
        price: 21.90,
       image: "../images/black-shirt.jpg"
    }
    ];

export default data;
```

In your main file:

```
return {
<div>
   <ul>
        {data.map(item =><img key={Math.random()} src={require(`../images/${item.image}.jpg`)} /> 
    </ul>
</div>
;
}
```